# How does Google Analytics influences the speed of the website's loading? Can there be conflicts between few analytics instruments?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

The web-developer don't want to insert Google Analytics code into the website, because he is sure, that it would affect the speed of the website's loading badly, despite the fact that I have pointed at the possibility of using the asynchronous code. What is the real influence of the GA's code on speed of website's loading and working?

How does using of other analytics instruments (for example, Yandex Metrica) on the same site can influence the accuracy or stability of working of Google Analytics? Whether this factor can lower the speed of loading and working of the website in addition?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of factors to why or how Google Analytics code may slow down a website. Is it a shared hosting? Where have you placed the analytics code? Did you put it at the top of the pages? Or at the bottom?

Good practise would be to add the analytics code before the `</body>` tag along with other externally sourced JS.

If Google Analytics code slows down your website, it is highly likely that using other analytics instruments will have the same effect.

You might want to run the website through a site-speed-checker like the one at Pingdom or Google's own to see whether it's the analytics code, or something else like bad compression (if you're not using gzip compression) or high-res uncompressed images etc that are actually slowing down your website.

It is also probably a good idea to test both with the analytics code and without to see if there is a significant change in load time. And please do it for multiple simultaneous requests and not just a single request. If you can provide this data, it might be helpful in understanding what's going on!

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Removed question about servers bandwidth based on comment from Eike Pierstorff!

Comment: Thanks for information. Yeah, I know, that it is recommended to place Analytics code before the </head> tag. But I was sure, that using of asynchronous code and the small size of script will guarantee almost total absence of change of speed of the website's loading. I'll talk about aspects that you mentioned with the web-developer. But what about using few analytics instruments at the same time?

Comment: @1Vityai1 Not, not before `</head>` you want it before the body ends (i.e. before `</body>`). You're right, the difference should be negligible with and without the code. Sure, you can use multiple tracking codes from multiple vendors if you like. I know a lot of companies do this because they need different kinds of data offered by different analytics instruments.

Comment: @1Vityai1 The analytics files is hosted with Google, so the bandwidth of the server does not really affect how quickly it is loaded.  More generally I'd say that your web developer makes the same mistake as this answer by assuming that browsers haven't moved on since Douglas Crockford made his recommendations on how to improve load speed. The one thing I agree with is that you should use a testing tool, since it will show that you worry needlessly (at least as far as GA is concerned).

Comment: @EikePierstorff is correct. The servers bandwidth would not affect. Silly me. I have edited my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: @0x23212f - here is the source article about recomendations of using of Google Analytics, which I've found from translated Russian web-magazine (look at the second paragraph): [link](https://translate.google.ru/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmsmagazine.ru%2Flibrary%2Fitems%2Fweb-analytics%2Faccuracy-of-data-in-google-analytics%2F&edit-text=&act=url)